# Is there an easy way to make Javascript apps SEO friendly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I've been looking at using a new workflow process for web development. Yemoan, Grunt, and Bower with AngularJS seems like a great solution for front-end development. The only downside is that the SEO is absolutely horrible. This seems like a HUGE component of the business decision driving adoption of these services yet I can't find any solutions.

What's a solid solution for making SEO-friendly javascript apps?

Comment: What have you discovered already by Googling the subject?

Comment: Disable js in you browser and make the content that should be visible to search engines reachable.

Comment: @osi So far I've found this: https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo. However it's crazy to me that URLs would have `/?_escaped_fragment_=/` appended to them. Is that really the best that there is?

Comment: Might be helpful: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/serious-angular-seo.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO and not programming as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't believe it is off topic. It isn't an SEO question at heart. It's an AngularJS question.

Comment: @t.niese If you disable js in the browser, then anything using Angular should NOT work. Angular is centered around single page apps (all ajax) and data-binding. The answer isn't degradation, it's snapshots (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

The current standard practice for making ajax heavy sites/apps SEO friendly is to use snapshots. See the google tutorial on this here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot and here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

To summarize, you add this tag `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` to your DOM. The crawler will see this and redirect itself from `www.example.com` to `www.example.com?_escaped_fragment_=` where it will be expecting the snapshot of the page.

You could manually copy the html from your site after all ajax is finished, and create your snapshot files yourself. However, this could be quite a nuisance. Instead, you could use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to automate this process for you. Personally, I am going to use `.htaccess` to send the `escaped_fragment` requests to a single php file which has cached markup created from the content manager when the edits were made. This allows it to recreate the markup for crawlers to view (but no functionality for humans).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relevant piece of info from [Debunking 10 common KnockoutJS myths](http://lorefnon.me/2012/08/11/debunking-10-common-knockoutjs-myths.html).  I assume it applies more or less equally to Angular.

> Graceful degradation in absense of javascript depends on the way your
>   application has been architectured. Although KO being a pure
>   javascript library, does not offer any support for graceful
>   degradation in absence of javascript, nevertheless unlike many of the
>   competing technologies it does not hinder graceful degradation.
>
> To create a KO application that degrades gracefully, just ensure that
>   the initial state of the page that is rendered by the server suffices
>   to convey the information that a user should see in absence of
>   javascript. Fallback mechanisms (eg simple forms and links) should be
>   available that provide the complete (or partial) application
>   functionality in absence of javascript. Then when you create your view
>   models you can instantiate them from the data already available from
>   the DOM and future data can be loaded via ajax without refreshing the
>   page.
>
> A good example for this functionality can be a grid. The basic HTML
>   page served by the server can contain a simple HTML table with support
>   for traditional links for pagination. Then you can create your view
>   models from the data present in the table ( or ajax if a bit of
>   redundant data load does not matter for you) and utilize KO for
>   interactive bindings.
>
> Since KO does not use special inline markup or custom html tags, but
>   rather simple data-bind attributes which are anyways not visible in
>   absence of javascript, it does not hinder graceful degradation.

Comment: There are two ways to make javascript apps SEO-friendly - 1. Using White hat Cloaking and 2. Using services like BromBone or Prerender. For More details see - [HOW TO MAKE JAVASCRIPT APPS SEO-FRIENDLY](http://nodejsmongodb.com/post/how-to-make-your-javascript-apps-seo-friendly/)